# Typescript cannot find find name

Tags: angular, typescript

I have class OpMarker and I import this class `import {OpMarker} form '/../'`
and I have declare `private selectedMarkers: OpMarker[] = []`

I must implement `selectedMarker.xyz` my error:

> Cannot find name 'selectedMarker'. Did you mean 'selectedMarkers'?

Comment: But... the error message is pretty clear isn’t it? It even asks you if you meant `selectedMarkers`

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not use `selectedMarker`, you use `selectedMarkers` which is an `OpMarker array`

Answer (score 0):

You must call `selectedMarkers` and not `selectedMarker`